# How to exclude specific files from vue-cli-3 build?

Tags: optimization, webpack, config, vue-cli-3, monaco-editor

Current configuration of project is:

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglify-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ["vuex-persist", "vuex-persistedstate"],
    exclude: [
        /w*worker.js\w*/g
    ],
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: false,
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                minSize: 10000, 
                maxSize: 250000, 
            },
            nodeEnv: "production",
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [
                new UglifyJsPlugin({
                    extractComments: 'false',
                    parallel: true,
                }),
            ],
            removeEmptyChunks: true,
            removeAvailableModules: true,
            mergeDuplicateChunks: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
                languages: ['javascript', 'css', 'html', 'typescript', 'json']
            })
        ]
    },
};
```

So, the problem was that vue parse the language worker files of the monaco-editor module. If I remove optimization options, in output I obtain the following not parsed files (worker.js)

[image]

But if I keep this optimization options, as a result, the following error occurs in the console

[image]

So the question is, how do I exclude this worker files from parsing?
Thank you in advance!